# Change permissions on /var/www to I can copy files from other systems

Tags: windows, linux, permissions, apache-http-server

I have a NTFS drive mounted at /media/bigbrother as my user. I have no trouble reading or writing to files here. I just created a link to /var/www using:

```
ln -s /var/www /media/bigbrother/
```

The link is there however, I can't even open the folder. How should I go about getting access. So that I'm able to copy files from other systems on the network.

Comment: What are you using to "copy files from other systems"? SFTP? NFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just changed the document root to a www folder on the share. This is how.

Created www folder in /media/bigbrother

Edit the sites-available using nano with this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

changed both /var/www to /media/bigbrother/www

ctrl+o to save, and press enter
ctrl+x to exit nano

restart apache

The www folder is now accessible from the other computers that have /media/bigbrother mapped.